# Keep having right padded pixels on my page with bootstrap 4+ and AOS

Tags: html, css, web

I am redesigning one of my website using bootstrap 4.4.1 and other libs such as mdb, aos, animate, boxicons, ...

I am not proficient in all this web development planet but striving to keep the code as clean as possible. I have a very annoying problem with extra pixels padded on the right side of my page where I didn't ask for any... (obviously..)

I put a quick a dirty "workaround" to remove the horizontal scrollbar and that fixes it for large display but the problem is even more appearant on a mobile device for which I also removed the horizontal scroll capability.

I looked into many other different posts referring a similar problem and tried many of the suggested solutions without success unfortunately...

The site and code can be seen here: [www.lesrevolins.fr/maquette2/](http://www.lesrevolins.fr/maquette2)

To clearly see what is wrong, I suggest you view it on a mobile device as it is obvious the right side is filled with blanks even though I am using container-fluid with proper definitions of rows and columns.

Any help on that would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
ElGrapho

**EDIT:**

I have made a stripped version which can be seen here where the problem is reproduced: [stripped version with problem](http://www.lesrevolins.fr/maquette2/index2.html) (I have removed the locking of the horizontal bar so it can be better seen)

From code perspective this is the structure in short:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 // Viewport definition, css inclusions etc..
</head>

<body> 

 <section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     // Standard bootstrap code example for navigation menu
    </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     // Standard bootstrap code example for carousel
    </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     // Some basic text using <p></p> on one column and an image on the second column with <img>
    </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     // Basic call to a parallax effect (from simpleParallax lib)
    </div>
  </div>
 </section>

</body>
```

If someone knows what is going on here, I would love to heard from it.

Comment: You'll need to 1. show some code in your post and 2. provide a stripped back example, where you recreate the issue in a simplistic setup. If you aren't able to do these, it isn't very likely you'll receive an answer on Stack Overflow. You could take a more general problem like this to chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Djave. I have edited the post and updated in short with stripped live example. Hopefully, someone could see what I can't :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found the origin of the problem so I thought it would be wise to update it here for others who may run in the same issue as I did.

I edited the summary to reflect the usage of the AOS (Animate On Scroll) library.

The issue is a bug with the translate property in fade left transitions. Solution is put as hidden overflow on x (that's an acceptable fix for now).

Bug can be found on AOS github, issue number #285. Hope that helps!